# Nested external configuration classes in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to inject my `application.yml` into a nested `Map` like this:

**application.yml**

```yaml
components:
  component1:
    host: host1
    port: 1111
  component2:
    host: host2
    port: 2222
  component3:
    host: host3
    port: 3333
```

**MyComponents.java**

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
public class MyComponents {
  Map<String, MyComponent> components;

  public class MyComponent {
    String host;
    Integer port;
    
    //empty constructor, getters, setters
  }

  //empty constructor, getters, setters
}
```

But even if I don't instantiate the object (`@Autowire`), I'm getting the following error message:

> org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'components[component1]' of bean class [package.path.MyComponents]: Could not instantiate property type [package.path.MyComponents$MyComponent] to auto-grow nested property path: java.lang.InstantiationException: package.path.MyComponents$MyComponent

How do I get the configuration into my class layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner `class` `MyComponent` has to be `static`:

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
public class MyComponents {
  Map<String, MyComponent> components;

  public static class MyComponent {
    String host;
    Integer port;
    
    //empty constructor, getters, setters
  }

  //empty constructor, getters, setters
}
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30488580/2) to the question [Nested external configuration classes in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488580/nested-external-configuration-classes-in-spring-boot) by the OP [Squall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1450698/squall) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>